# Another React Hook Question - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I really seem to have trouble with react and hooks. I know that the problem could be do to react-dom. I am watching a tutorial that does it with 5 and im using 6. I looked at the documentation, but I honestly can't find the issue. It worked for my homepage, but now the product page doesn't work and I honestly couldn't find anything on past answers about this problem. Does anybody have an idea?? Thanks!

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { listProductDetails } from '../actions/productActions'



function ProductScreen({match}) {


    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
    const {loading, error, product} = productDetails

    useEffect(() =>{
        dispatch(listProductDetails(match.params.id))

    },[])
```

ProductActions.js:

```
export const listProductDetails = (id) =>  async(dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST})


        const { id } = useParams();

        const {data} =  await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)

        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message, 
        })
    }
}
```

productReducer.js:

```
export const productDetailsReducer = (state={product:{reviews:[]}},action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
            return {loading:true, ...state}

        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
            return {loading:false, product:action.payload}

        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
            return {loading:false, error: action.payload}
        
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

store.js:

```
import { legacy_createStore as createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import {productListReducer,productDetailsReducer} from './reducers/productReducers'


const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
})
const initialState = {}
const middleware = [thunk]
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, 
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store
```

Comment: If you want to get `match` as a param, you need to wrap that component with `withRouter`. You can get URL params with use of `useParams` instead of `match`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const listProductDetails = (id) =>  async(dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST})


        const { id } = useParams();
[...]
```

You are passing `id` as argument of `listProductDetails` then you are redefining it inside the function.
Move `const { id } = useParams();` into `ProductScreen` and pass it as argument to function instead of using `match`.

Also `listProductDetails` returns an async function that takes `dispatch` as argument. So don't call `dispatch(listProductDetails(id))` but instead call `listProductDetails(id)(dispatch)`.

Also calling dispatch within the api is not a good idea. You generally want action function to return something to be dispatched within a React Component.

```
function ProductScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { id } = useParams();
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (id) => {
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST });
      dispatch(await listProductDetails(id));
    };

    fetchData(id);
  }, [dispatch, id]);
  return <div>APP</div>;
}
```

In ProductActions.js

```
export const listProductDetails = async (id) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);
    return {
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    };
  }
};
```